# Confused with a symbol in an UML diagram

Tags: design-patterns, uml, class-diagram

What does the black arrow with a small circle that points from the `Subject` to the `Observer` mean?

I have tried searching for it on Google but could not find the desired explanation. Any help is appreciated. Thank you very much.

[image]

Comment: Hello. This question is very useful, as many people confuse the notation of GoF diagrams with UML. I've slightly edited your question and tried to make the title more specific, so that it can help others confronted with similar questions. I hesitated between "symbol" and  "notation". I hope it is ok for you. If not don't hesitate to rollback or edit further

Answer (score 4):

This diagram, was originally published on page 294 of the **[GoF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns)** looks like UML but is **not UML**. And there is a good reason for this:  this book was written before UML was adopted. As explained in the same book p. 363 to 367, the notation used is a variant of [James Rumbaugh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Rumbaugh)'s **[OMT notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-modeling_technique)**.

So here all possible point of view of your question:

1. **What does the notation mean in this diagram** (in OMT)?

   The black circle in OMT means the multiplicity "zero or more".  OMT knows only bidirectional association. The GoF variant  introduced the black plain arrow to indicate a unidirectional association.  So, this diagram means a navigable one-to-many association, i.e. there could be several observer instances for the same subject instance, and the subjects keep references to their observers.
2. **How would you express the same meaning in UML?**

   In UML, this directional aspect would be indicated with an open-headed navigation arrow, although the dot notation would better reflect GoF's intention (see point 3). The circle would be replaced with a `*` multiplicity near the arrow head.  Btw, the role *`observers`* would be on the opposite side than it is here.
3. **What would this circle mean in an UML diagram**?

   UML uses the little circle at the end of an association, the so-called "[dot notation](https://www.omg.org/ocup-2/documents/getting_it_right_on_the_dot.pdf)", to tell that the end of the association is owned by the class at the opposite side.  As explained in the linked article, the dot notation can be combined with the navigability notation but the arrow-head would have to be open-headed.

Comment: I used OMT back in the 90’s. I don’t think the association names were ever on the blunt ends of arrows, were they?

Comment: @JimL. I used Booch at that time ;-) But I cross checked in the OMT book: indeed, all association names are shown as in UML on the center of the association. However the role name were at the ends of the association exactly like UML, and with the same logic than UML. Page 34 there is the typical example of  Company with a one to many association with Person. The association name is "works for" whereas the role on the side of Person is employee and the role of the Company is employer. GoF were wrong in this regard as in all their diagrams the role is on the wrong side.

Answer (score 0):

This diagram does not conform to the UML spec. The white triangles should be arrowheads at the ends of the lines that point to the superclasses, and the black arrows look wrong. A ball at the end indicates property ownership in UML, and that property name is missing. Where did you find this?

Comment: It is indeed not UML. It's GoF and the notation is in a variant of pre-uml OMT (the notationinvented by J.Rumbaugh before he joined his peers to invent UML)